# Postgresql Remove $ sign money datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column (type numeric). I type cast it to Money in postgresql as

```
Cast (amount_total as money)
```

When i query data it shows like

```
$ 1,026,073.00
```

How to remove this dollar sign? 
And if possible can i replace it with a *indian rupee* sign?

Comment: what is LC_CTYPE for India?..

Comment: Why do you cast the `numeric` to `money` in the first place? What do you expect to gain from that? And, as *always*, provide your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, check if your OS supports it:

```
bash# locale -a | grep en_IN
    en_IN
    en_IN.utf8
```

then SQL:

```
SQL> set LC_N

SQL> set LC_MONETARY='en_IN';
SET
SQL> select 1.2::float8::numeric::money;
 money
--------
 ₹ 1.20
(1 row)
```

[read](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/locale.html)

and in case you just want to get rid of dollar sign, substr from second symbol (will work for your current en_US locale):

```
td=# SELECT substr('12.34'::float8::numeric::money::text,2);
 substr
--------
 12.34
(1 row)
```

Comment: On running set LC_MONETARY='RU_ru';  ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "RU_ru" It is throwing this error

Comment: en_IN does not work for me. but I believe OS should support it in firts place

Comment: @ManishGupta try en_IN

Comment: I just removed the dollar sign. The rupee sign wasn't necessary. Thanks